# Using Servicestack, how do you cache result sets when using AutoQuery with a ServiceSource?

Tags: c#, caching, .net-core, servicestack, servicestack-autoquery

I am trying to use ServiceStack's AutoQuery with a service source, but am either unable to get caching working correctly, or have misunderstood how it is supposed to work.

What I am trying to achieve to to add query functionality to an 'edge' microservice which calls an internal service that serves up a complete list of data.

Minimal code to reproduce my problem:

```cs
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebHost host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel((builderContext, options) => options.Configure(builderContext.Configuration.GetSection("Kestrel")))
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
        await host.RunAsync();
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {}
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseServiceStack(new AppHost());
        app.Run(context => Task.FromResult(0));
    }
}

public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AppHost() : base("Hello Web Services", typeof(HelloService).Assembly){ }

    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {
        container.AddSingleton<ICacheClient, MemoryCacheClient>(); // Otherwise HostContext.Cache is null
        Plugins.Add(new AutoQueryDataFeature { MaxLimit = 3, IncludeTotal = true }.AddDataSource(ctx => ctx.ServiceSource<string>(new Hello(), HostContext.Cache, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))));
    }
}

// Request DTO
[Route("/hello")]
[Route("/hello/{Name}")]
public class Hello : QueryData<NameDto>
{
    [QueryDataField(Condition = "StartsWith", Field = nameof(Name))]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class NameDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class HelloService : Service
{
    public IAutoQueryData AutoQuery { get; set; }
    public async Task<object> Any(Hello query)
    {
        //Imagine I was making a service call to another microservice here...
        var data = new List<NameDto> { new NameDto { Name = "Bob" }, new NameDto { Name = "George" }, new NameDto { Name = "Baldrick" }, new NameDto { Name = "Nursey" }, new NameDto { Name = "Melchett" }, new NameDto { Name = "Kate" } };

        DataQuery<NameDto> dataQuery = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(query, Request, new MemoryDataSource<NameDto>(data, query, Request));

        return AutoQuery.Execute(query, dataQuery);
    }
}
```

Nuget packages: Mircosoft.AspNetCore.All (2.2.1) and ServiceStack (5.4.0)

So, in a console (.NET Core 2.2), the above code will spin up and listen on port 5000.

If I query, I get my list, which is limited to the number of results as expected, and I can also skip / take as expected.

However, every time I invoke the service method, the results are not cached (which is specified when I registered the plug-in - cache for 5 minutes) and if I put a breakpoint in the service method, the list of 'Names' is re-created every time. This happens even if I make the same request to the service.

I'd like to be able to cache the result set (in memory is fine) and only hit the service method when the cache expires. What am I doing wrong (or misunderstanding) here?

**Edit**

Code that I used to try out Mythz suggestion... now I don't get any autoquery features working at all.

```cs
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebHost host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel((builderContext, options) => options.Configure(builderContext.Configuration.GetSection("Kestrel")))
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
        await host.RunAsync();
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseServiceStack(new AppHost());
        app.Run(context => Task.FromResult(0));
    }
}

public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AppHost() : base("Hello Web Services", typeof(HelloService).Assembly){ }

    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {
        container.AddSingleton<ICacheClient, MemoryCacheClient>();

        Plugins.Add(new AutoQueryDataFeature { MaxLimit = 5 }
            .AddDataSource(ctx => ctx.ServiceSource<GithubRepo>(ctx.Dto.ConvertTo<QueryGithubRepo>(),
                HostContext.Cache, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))));
    }


}


public class QueryGithubRepo : QueryData<GithubRepo>
{
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Organization { get; set; }
}

public class GithubRepo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Homepage { get; set; }
    public int Watchers_Count { get; set; }
    public int Stargazers_Count { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public string Full_Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created_at { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Updated_At { get; set; }

    public bool Has_Downloads { get; set; }
    public bool Fork { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; } // https://api.github.com/repos/NetCoreWebApps/bare
    public string Html_Url { get; set; }
    public bool Private { get; set; }

    public GithubRepo Parent { get; set; } // only on single result, e.g: /repos/NetCoreWebApps/bare
}

public class NameDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class HelloService : Service
{    
    public object Get(QueryGithubRepo request)
    {
        if (request.User == null && request.Organization == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("User");

        var url = request.User != null
            ? $"https://api.github.com/users/{request.User}/repos"
            : $"https://api.github.com/orgs/{request.Organization}/repos";

        return url.GetJsonFromUrl(requestFilter: req => req.UserAgent = GetType().Name)
            .FromJson<List<GithubRepo>>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using AutoQuery in your Service implementation that's just a [Custom AutoQuery implementation](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#custom-autoquery-implementations) not a [AutoQuery Service Data Source](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-service) which queries the results of a normal Service.

In this case it sounds like you do want a cacheable Auto Query Service Data Source which the docs shows an example of in its [GetGithubRepos Service](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-service#getgithubrepos) which makes an API call to GitHub's 3rd Party API:

```
public class QueryGithubRepo : QueryData<GithubRepo> 
{
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Organization { get; set; }
}

public object Get(GetGithubRepos request)
{
    if (request.User == null && request.Organization == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("User");

    var url = request.User != null
        ? $"https://api.github.com/users/{request.User}/repos"
        : $"https://api.github.com/orgs/{request.Organization}/repos";

    return url.GetJsonFromUrl(requestFilter:req => req.UserAgent = GetType().Name)
        .FromJson<List<GithubRepo>>();
}
```

Then you register it is a [cached Service Data Source](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-service#register-data-sources) when registering the Service DataSource:

```
Plugins.Add(new AutoQueryDataFeature { MaxLimit = 100 }
    .AddDataSource(ctx => ctx.ServiceSource<GithubRepo>(ctx.Dto.ConvertTo<GetGithubRepos>(), 
        HostContext.Cache, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)));
);
```

You can use `HostContext.LocalCache` to cache it in the local Memory Cache, instead of the registered `ICacheClient` [caching provider](https://docs.servicestack.net/caching).

Comment: I have followed your advice and have updated my original question with the complete code I used to re-create the QueryGitHub example you provided. I'm struggling a bit as I can't get your example working. I get a result from GitHub when querying for user 'bob' but it looks like AutoQuery is not getting involved at all - it just executes the service method.

Comment: @Jay You've not followed my example and are still trying to override a Custom AutoQuery implementation instead of using the Service Data Source. Look closely at my example, the  `QueryGithubRepo` AutoQuery Service queries `GithubRepo` results that is provided by the normal `GetGithubRepos` service where it's registered as the data source for `GitHubRepo`, i.e. `ctx.ServiceSource<GithubRepo>(ctx.Dto.ConvertTo<GetGithubRepos>()`, you're doing it backwards and are registering the `QueryGithubRepo` AutoQuery Service as the data source for `GithubRepo` whilst at the same time overriding its impl.

Comment: @Jay If you want to test my example, use the existing classes + impl as-is.  i.e. You should not be overriding the AutoQuery Service, the `QueryGithubRepo` is used to call a normal `GetGithubRepos` service which is registered as the Service Data Source for `GitHubRepo` with `ctx.ServiceSource<GithubRepo>`.